# JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource /WEB-INF/servlet/view error for Liferay 4.3 + Spring Portlet in Websphere

Tags: websphere

I was able to successfully deploy liferay in both websphere 6.1 and 7.0 version.

Also my portlets which are developed using spring portlet mvc are listed in add content.

I am using the following view resolver of spring framework to route the control to respective portlet jsps

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/html/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

When I include my portlet under the page, I get the following error which is related to not finding the view(i.e jsp) properly... but I was able to debug and see that my controller is getting called properly and view name was also returned.

The same set up works fine in Jboss, please help if I am missing anything specific to websphere...

Thanks in advance... Expecting your responses

> JSP Processing Error HTTP Error Code: 404
>
> Error Message: JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource
>   /WEB-INF/servlet/view
>
> Root Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JSPG0036E: Failed to find
>   resource /WEB-INF/servlet/view at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.findWrapper(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:376)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:336)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:673)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:137)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:251)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet.renderView(ViewRendererServlet.java:111)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet.processRequest(ViewRendererServlet.java:84)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet.doGet(ViewRendererServlet.java:65)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831) at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:937)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:673)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:245)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:87)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.render(DispatcherPortlet.java:1081)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doRenderService(DispatcherPortlet.java:811)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:475)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.doDispatch(FrameworkPortlet.java:445)
>   at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233) at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:107)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831) at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:937)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:673)
>   at com.liferay.portlet.CachePortlet._invoke(CachePortlet.java:354) at
>   com.liferay.portlet.CachePortlet.render(CachePortlet.java:201) at
>   com.ibm._jsp._render_5F_portlet._jspService(_render_5F_portlet.java:1324)
>   at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831) at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>   at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:239)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:673)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.renderPortlet(PortalUtil.java:1517)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processPortlet(RuntimePortletUtil.java:165)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processPortlet(RuntimePortletUtil.java:102)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePortletUtil.java:270)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePortletUtil.java:189)
>   at com.ibm._jsp._portlet._jspService(_portlet.java:762) at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831) at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>   at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:239)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:673)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.includeLayoutContent(LayoutAction.java:291)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:174)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:157)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718) at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:287)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:522)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831) at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:341)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:130)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831) at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
>   at com.liferay.filters.strip.StripFilter.doFilter(StripFilter.java:92)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
>   at
>   com.liferay.filters.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:122)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
>   at
>   com.liferay.filters.secure.SecureFilter.doFilter(SecureFilter.java:144)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
>   at
>   com.liferay.filters.doubleclick.DoubleClickFilter.doFilter(DoubleClickFilter.java:135)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.layoutcache.LayoutCacheFilter.doFilter(LayoutCacheFilter.java:188)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.doFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:117)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.doFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:166)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
>   at
>   com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sessionid.SessionIdFilter.doFilter(SessionIdFilter.java:85)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)

Answer (score 1):

Solution Found :) :-

Extend the spring DispatcherPortlet class and write your own custom portlet class.

Override the render method, most of the implementation is same as base class render method implementation.

Add these lines at the end of the method -

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request);
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(response);
//constant below indicate the url pattern of view renderer servlet configured in web.xml
RequestDispatcher portletRequestDispatcher = httpRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/servlet/view");

portletRequestDispatcher.include(httpRequest, httpResponse);
```

Note : dont forget to configure your custom portlet class in portlet.xml for your portlets.

Hope its useful for you too.

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs in newer versions when a servlet forward call is made instead of a servlet include.

I observed this using Apache Tiles 2 and Spring Portlet MVC 4.3 on WebSphere 8.5 for example. In this case -if you are using Spring's `viewResolver` bean you can configure it to force a servlet-include:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver">
    <property name="alwaysInclude" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Notice that Tiles 2 support is deprecated in Spring MVC 4.3. I just added this solution in case someone has trouble with existing code.

Regarding Tiles, another way is to force the servlet-include manually. You need to set the request attribute `ServletUtil.FORCE_INCLUDE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME` to `true`. However, I don't know if this works if you set it in the portlet request as the portlet request attributes might not be available in the servlet request anymore. As far as I know there is no official way to get the servlet request object from the portlet request object. Thus, [here](http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/Tiles-2-2-2-and-portlets-td5710415.html) someone suggests to create a servlet filter for "*.tiles" that sets the attribute. I didn't try this, however.